# sudo apt-get install will not work

Tags: package-management

I am sorry, I may be repeating a question, but whenever I try `sudo apt-get install (something)`, I cannot get it to work. This is the outcome.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 guake : Depends: python-glade2 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: python-keybinder but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: python-vte but it is not going to be installed
 kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 
15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I tried: `sudo apt-get -f install` which still does not work. Please help.

How should I get either one of them to work?

It would be great if I got an answer back. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running first only `sudo apt-get -f install` and then `sudo apt-get install packagename`

Comment: "Does not work" isn't useful for troubleshooting. Please post the exact and complete error message when doing *sudo apt-get -f install*. And what Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: Yes, I tried both, but they do not work

Comment: Like celticwarrior said, post the output of "sudo apt-get -f install".

Comment: It seems you misunderstood CelticWarrior's comment. We don't a need a confirmation that `apt-get install -f` results in an error. We need the ***full, verbatim output* of `sudo apt-get install -f`** that includes the error message(s). To capture the output of a command you can either 1) select, copy & paste the terminal content or 2) [save it to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

remove sources.list file.and create new sources.list...

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)

Now install anything!

Answer (score -3):

You tried installing the Kubuntu-desktop package?
You should not try installing that again.It seems to be broken in Ubuntu 16.04 since it seems that the package doesn't actually include dependencies for the Telepathy IM client,resulting in broken dependencies,which results in broken apt.
It's a good idea to have Synaptic package manager installed to be able to deal more easily with these kind of issues.
But,back to the point,
Open the terminal and type in:

```
sudo dpkg -P unity-scope-gdrive account-plugin-google account-plugin-facebook
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: -1 Give more details for A) why they should not install `kubuntu-desktop` and B) why you suggested the solution that you did. Also, please use spaces after your puctuation.

Comment: You cannot install kubuntu-desktop on an Ubuntu install without this happening due to conflicting packages (both packages contain the same name file.) This is noted elsewhere on this site I'm sure...

Comment: And people who down-voted this should get informed first before doing such.